# How to clear context after each test class in spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit5

I am using spring-boot 3.0.12 with JUnit 5. We do not employ any sort of parallelism during test execution. All tests are executed one after another.

Can someone let me know how can I clear the spring context after all the tests are executed in a test class?

I am aware of `@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)`. Here I am asking if there exists some way where I do not have to put `@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)` in every test class annotated with `@SpringBootTest`. Is there any configuration in SpringBoot test which will do this automatically or is there a way for me to write a [TestExecutionListener](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.3/api/org/junit/platform/launcher/TestExecutionListener.html) from which I would be able to clear the context programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can implement the TestExecutionListener class and overide the afterTestClass method like

```
@Override
public void afterTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
    testContext.getApplicationContext().close();
}
```

Also, add this in you test property file, addd
org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListener=com.example.ClearContextTestExecutionListener

om.example.ClearContextTestExecutionListener should be the replaced to your execution listener class

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use your own annotation like following

```
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface IntegrationTest {

}
```

And then, use it instead of `@SpringBootTest`